# App not reading current/updated plist . Caching issue with plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, plist

I have a plist which is an array of 10 index ; which is read first time correctly, Now i  deleted some or 5 last index from that plist array form plist xml, After that on fetching it will still return array of 10 index while now it should return array of 5 indexes, is it coming from cache. How could i solve this???
 This is how i am reading plist data by calling this:-

```
NSArray *plistDataArray = [self GetSavedPlistDatawithPlistIdentifier:myPlistName];
```

And the function is :-

```
-(NSMutableArray*)GetSavedPlistDatawithPlistIdentifier :(NSString*)plistfilename {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",plistfilename]];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistfilename ofType:@"plist"];
}

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;

NSMutableArray *tempfeedBackArr =(NSMutableArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];

return tempfeedBackArr;
}
```

Comment: You could try cleaning (Cmd-Opt-Shift-K) and rebuilding to ensure the updated version of the plist is included in the product.

Comment: Yes, i have updated version of plist, which i have double checked.

Comment: Can you provide some more details like code snippets for deleting objects from plist and reading the plist?

Comment: All I see above is that you read from the file. Never writing to it.

Comment: Yes bcoz i not writting in it. In previous version of live app i have 10 index now in next version i have only 5 index . so i am just deleting last 5 index  from directly plist or interface.

Comment: The code snippet you added seems to read file from app bundle if file does not exist in Document directory. In this case, if there is no file at document directory, you will always get the same array which you got first time. If this is not the case, provide the code snippet you are using for deleting the array objects.

Answer (score 0):

Something about your question and comments doesn't make sense. The code you posted is reading from the documents directory, which is runtime directory. Then you say you're not writing it.

The documents directory gets written to during the running of your app, and persists between updates. If you build and run a new version of your app, it will still contain the same contents in the documents directory.

Comment: As I have menstion I am not writing anything in plist at runtime.. I am just just delete some index before build form xml file of plist.

Comment: The plist won't be in the documents directory in the fist place unless you put it there at runtime.